# Como continuar chat con una persona en whatsapp api? Con node js

Tags: nodejs, api, whatsapp, whatsapp-webhook

Estoy trabajando en una integración de las apis de whatsapp con node. Hasta ahora todo funciona correctamente. Las respuestas, los tipos de mensajes etc.
Ahora, lo que estoy intentando sin éxito es que la conversación que en inicio fue respondida por la api pueda seguir de persona a persona sin que se disparen los eventos de respuesta de las apis que fueron configurados anteriormente.

Es decir, que una persona pueda seguir recibiendo los mensajes del usuario que inicia la conversación sin intervención de la api al menos hasta finalizar la conversación o hasta que se cumpla un tiempo determinado o hasta utilizar de vuelta una palabra clave.

Espero haberme explicado.

Esta es la lógica del código que se envía a un controlador. Lo que estaba pensando era tal vez borrar el ultimo condicional de modo de a que no responda nada si las palabras contestadas no coinciden con ninguna de las opciones.

```js
function Procesar(textoUsuario, numero) {
  textoUsuario = textoUsuario.toLowerCase();
  let modelos = [];
  if (textoUsuario.includes("hola") || textoUsuario.includes("buen dia")) {
    let modelo = modelosWhatsapp.MensajeTexto(
      " Hola, gracias por escribirnos. \nSelecciona alguna de las opciones que siguen para poder ayudarte.\n1-Productos o Servicios\n2-Solicitar un plan o servicio\n3-Contactos\n4-Sugerencias\n5-Volver al menú de inicio\n6-Chatear con un representante",
      numero
    );
    modelos.push(modelo);
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("1")) {
    ...
    );
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("2")) {
 ...
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("3")) {
 ...
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("4")) {
 ...
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("5")) {
 ...
  } else if (textoUsuario.includes("6")) {
    let modelo = modelosWhatsapp.MensajeTexto(
      "Por favor aguarda, en breve te asiste un representante. Muchas gracias!",
      numero
    );
    modelos.push(modelo);
  } else {
    let modelo = modelosWhatsapp.MensajeTexto(
      "No entiendo. Puedes elegir alguna otra opción?",
      numero
    );
    modelos.push(modelo);
  }

  modelos.forEach((modelo) => {
    servicios.SendMessageWhatsapp(modelo);
  });
}
module.exports = {
  Procesar,
};
```

Como comenté, lo que intento es que al seleccionar la opción 6, no responda la api indicando que no entiende la respuesta. Hay alguna manera de hacer que las respuestas se reactiven solo con alguna palabra clave o después de X tiempo?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La API de WhatsApp no está diseñada para ese caso de uso.

Answer (score 0):

para una mejor respuesta seria bueno enviaras muestras de codigo de las funciones que estas utilizando para implementar la funcion Procesar, y si es la api cloud lo que estas utilizando.

Lo primero que deberías hacer es retirar el if else que dice

"No entiendo. Puedes elegir alguna otra opción?",

ya que dices en tu pregunta, ("lo que intento es que al seleccionar la opción 6, no responda la api indicando que no entiende la respuesta.").

Por otra parte para continuar una conversación de persona a persona  con tu cliente, solo lo puedes conseguir creando una interfaz donde veas los mensajes del cliente, y puedas enviar respuestas desde la interfaz(esto es lo que ofrecen muchos proveedores de la api en la web).

Otra forma, es enviarle al cliente un mensaje donde le indiques que le llegará un mensaje desde otro numero que corresponde al numero de atencion directa al cliente y con ese numero realizar la atención directa con tu cliente. Eso lo puedes hacer en la opción 6.

Ahora cuando dices ,¨la conversación que en inicio fue respondida por la api pueda seguir de persona a persona sin que se disparen los eventos de respuesta de las apis que fueron configurados anteriormente¨¨.

Es imposible que no se sigan disparando los eventos de los webhooks de mensajes.En la documentación dice lo siguiente:

> ***Error en la entrega de webhooks***
>
> Si enviamos una solicitud de webhook a tu punto de conexión y tu
> servidor responde con un código de estado HTTP que no es 200, o si no
> podemos entregar el webhook por otro motivo, seguiremos intentando
> cada vez con menos frecuencia hasta que la solicitud tenga éxito, por
> hasta 7 días.
>
> Ten en cuenta que los reintentos se enviarán a todas las apps que se
> hayan suscrito a los webhooks (y a sus campos correspondientes) en
> relación con la cuenta de WhatsApp Business. Esto puede dar como
> resultado que se dupliquen las notificaciones de webhook.

*referencia a la documentación*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks

para que estos webhooks no sean validos en tu aplicación ,te recomiendo guardarlos en una base de datos y desde ahi validar con el wamid de cada mensaje, para que sean ignorados por tu aplicación si ya han sido enviados.